# Opening a child form from another child form and set MDI to parent form - how to do?

Tags: c#, winforms, mdichild, mdiparent

I have a MDI form. within this MDI form I can open some child forms using:

This is within `MainForm`

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1;
f1.MdiParent = this; //this refers to MainForm (parent)
f1.Show();
```

This works as expected!

But Now, while I am in the child form (Form1 -> f1) I want to open another form as a child for `MainForm` but when I use `this` keyword it will reffer to `f1`. How can I open the new form within `f1` and set its `MdiParent` to `MainForm` ?

Comment: You probably could use this.MdiParent.  It is usually best to leave creating child windows to the parent.  Use an event to tell it to take action.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try assigning the parent form of your first child from:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2;
f2.MdiParent = this.ParentForm; //this refers to f1's parent, the MainForm
f2.Show();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 12):

Let us suppose that the second form is f2.Then, the code in form f1 to create a new form f2 in MDI parent form will be:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2;
f2.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
f2.Show();
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, not to argue with the "solution" that was listed... but if I'm understanding the request correctly and trying the above solution didnt work i would do the following....

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.MdiParent = MDIParent1.ActiveForm;
        f2.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us suppose that the second form is frm2.Then, the code in form frm1 to create a new form frm2 in MDI parent form will be: create new object then again retrived data mdiparent forms solved freeze dispose form

```vb
Dim dru as New frm2 '// another form call
dru = New frm2
dru.mdiparent = frm1 '// main forms
dru.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried all different solutions. Finally the one that worked for me was:

```
Dim ChildForm As New AddingText("")
' Make it a child of this MDI form before showing it.
ChildForm.MdiParent = MDIParent1
ChildForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
MDIParent1.m_ChildFormNumber += 1
ChildForm.Text = "Client Existent" & MDIParent1.m_ChildFormNumber
ChildForm.Show()
```

the hiccup is that could not be used in conjunction with ShowDialog(), but i can live with it.

Comment: Thanks for answering a 10-year-old question :)